# Flutter: How can I store user created objects in local storage and retrieve them into a ListView

Tags: json, object, local-storage, storage, flutter

I am recreating my app [Call Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=groovinchip.com.callmanager) in Flutter and I am having a very difficult time storing objects and retrieving them into a list. Using SharedPreferences and GSON works well for the full Android app, but as GSON does not exist in Flutter, it seems to me that storing onjects as JSON data is the way to go.

The flow should be as follows:
The user add a new call on the AddNewCall screen. This includes a name, phone number, and optional description'
When the user clicks the 'Save' button, a Call object is created from the text in those fields. The object is encoded into a String like this: `String jsonData = json.encode(newCallObject);`
The call JSON data is saved into the app's local storage using `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()`
The user is taken back to the main screen, where the JSON file will be loaded into the app asynchronously in the `initState()` method. 
The JSON data is decoded and added to a ListView
The problem I am experiencing is that as the JSON data is added to the file is Step 3, it will look like this: `{sampleData}{sampleData}` instead of being surrounded in `[]`, as an array. The app hiccups when reading in the file because of this. My solution thus far has been to parse the contents of the file into an array, stick an underscore in between the }{, and split the resulting String into an array of type String. It looks like this:

```
String jsonCalls = await file.readAsString();
jsonCalls = jsonCalls.replaceAll('}{', '}_{');
List<String> temp = jsonCalls.split('_');
```

So now I get an array with JSON strings in them, but I am stuck on being able to access the values in each JSON string. This whole approach that I'm taking seems way over-complicated too. There must be a better way, but I have googled like crazy and found nothing. Are you guys able to help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some suggestions

1. Flutter supports shared preferences using a [plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences), so it should feel familiar from Android.
2. `initState` is only called when the StatefulWidget is initialised the first time, so may not be a good place to expect to re-load changed information
3. Consider keeping your working state in memory, for example in a `List<Call>` to which you can readily add new Calls.
4. When you serialize this `List` to json it will be wrapped in brackets as expected. Write the whole List, overwriting the previous version.
5. Use the backing store (file or shared preferences) as the persistence between uses of your app, so read it once at startup, and write it each time you modify it in memory. The in-memory copy is the master while the app is running.

This should alleviate the need to hack the json as strings.

Maybe something like:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Call Manager',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Call> calls = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    load();
  }

  load() async {
    // initially populate calls by getting last value from shared preferences and parsing it
  }

  persist() async {
    // encode calls as json and write to share prefs
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Calls'),
      ),
      body: new ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: calls
            .map((call) => new ListTile(
                  title: new Text(call.phoneNumber),
                ))
            .toList(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push<Call>(
            context,
            new MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => new SecondPage(),
            ),
          ).then((newCall) {
            if (newCall != null) {
              setState(() {
                calls.add(newCall);
              });
              persist();
            }
          });
        },
        tooltip: 'New',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. Yes, but SharedPreferences in Flutter won't store an object as far as I can tell
2. didn't know this about initState(), thanks!
3. Not sure how I would implement this suggestion. How would I keep track of this List between screens?

Comment: 1 It will store a String, which is what json.encode gives you. 3 You could keep the list in the state of your home page. If you use Navigator.push to launch the second page, you can get a return value back in the main page when the second page closes. This could be the result of the second page, and you could add it to the list.

Comment: So you're saying the List would be a global variable?

Comment: No, part of the state of the home page.

Comment: Note on [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences): "Data may be persisted to disk asynchronously, and **there is no guarantee that writes will be persisted to disk after returning, so this plugin must not be used for storing critical data.**" (emphasis mine.)